# Get the URL for a Gmail label using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, url, label, gmail

I have a script that creates a new label in Gmail.  Since it is a new label, it is not associated with any email message, yet.  I would like to get the URL associated with the label using Apps Script.  I have simimlar code that gets the URL for a folder.

I do:
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labelName);

to get the label object.  I was hoping something like:

label.getUrl()

would return the URL for this label.  The script saves without error. It gets an error when I run it:

label.getUrl is not a function

Note that creating a folder object and then then doing:

newFolder.getUrl()

works fine.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: What is `the URL associated with the label`?

Comment: In the Gmail web interface, in the left panel, it lists all the labels you have .  If you right-click on one, it let's you copy a link for that label.  If you navigate to that link in a browser,  Gmail displays all the messages with that label.

I would like to capture that link with an Apps Script Gmailapp program and save it in a spreadsheet.